# VBA for SUMIF between different sheets

Tags: excel, vba

Please refer to the below code:

```
Dim glAcnew As Variant
Dim dummy As Variant, glnewTrans As Variant, count As Variant
count = 0
dummy = "data"
glnew = InputBox("Enter tab name for new GL Accounts", "GL Picker")
    Sheets(glnew).Select
Sheets.Add.Name = glnew & dummy & count
    Set glnewTrans = Worksheets(glnew & dummy & count)
Range("D7").Offset(0, count + 6).Select
    ActiveCell.Formula = "=(SUMIF('" & ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(glnew & dummy & count).Name & "'!A:A,Final!H7,'" & ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(glnew & dummy & count).Name & "'!B:B)"
```

This is giving me the following error:

```
Run-time error '1004'
Application-defined or object-defined error
```

Please help me solve this.
Thank you!

Comment: *This is giving me the following error* Which line? What are the value of your variables when the error raises? Did you try to debug it with F8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What sheet do you expect `Range("D7")` to belong to? I am pretty sure you are mixing them up.

I did a little bit of refactoring of your code - maybe with that you could find your error more easily:

```vb
Public Sub newVersion()

Dim dummy As String
dummy = "data"

Dim count As Long
count = 0

Dim glNew As String
glNew = InputBox("Enter tab name for new GL Accounts", "GL Picker")

Dim wsGlAccounts As Worksheet
Set wsGlAccounts = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(glNew)

Dim newName As String
newName = glNew & dummy & count

Dim wsNew As Worksheet
Set wsNew = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
wsNew.Name = newName

'Could it be that you want to fill D7 of wsGLAccounts?
With wsNew.Range("D7").Offset(0, count + 6)
    .Formula = "=(SUMIF('" & newName & "'!A:A,Final!H7,'" & newName & "'!B:B)"
End With

End Sub
```

Most important points:

- declare the correct type for the variables
- you don't need select
- reference ranges explicitly